# Makefile | Dependency on another Header file included in Header file

Tags: c++, makefile

Suppose I have below rule in `Makefile`.

```
test.o: test.cpp foo.h
        g++ -c -o test.o test.cpp
```

Now suppose `foo.h` includes `bar.h` as seen below.

```
user $ head -n 5 foo.h
#include"bar.h"
/*
.
.
*/
user $
```

Will the `test.o` be built again if there are any changes in `bar.h` ?

Or should I specifically mention `bar.h` in the rule as below:

```
test.o: test.cpp foo.h bar.h
        g++ -c -o test.o test.cpp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will the `test.o` be built again if there are any changes in `bar.h`?

**No. Make has no way of knowing about this dependency, or checking for changes in your `#include`s.**

Except, of course, if you leave handling header dependencies to the entity who *knows* about them: The compiler. **(Assuming GCC and GNU make in this example.)**

1. Don't list headers as dependencies *at all*.
2. Generate a list of *source* files in your project.

   ```make
   SRCFILES := ...
   ```
3. Generate a list of *dependency* files, one `.d` file for each `SRCFILE`.

   ```make
   DEPFILES := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.d,$(SRCFILES))
   ```
4. *Include* those dependency files into your Makefile. (The leading `-` means Make will not generate an error if they don't exist, e.g. on first compilation.)

   ```make
   -include $(DEPFILES)
   ```
5. Using a *generic* rule, let the compiler generate a list of the header dependencies during compilation of each source file.

   ```make
   %.o: %.cpp Makefile
       @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
   ```

   `-MMD` generates Make rules making the object files depend on any (non-system) header files included, named `*.d`. `-MP` adds dummy rules that avoid errors should a header file be *removed* from your sources.

Answer (score 3):

GCC (and probably Clang) can build a list of dependencies for you; This way, you can simply make your object files from their source (cpp) file:

```
depend: .depend

.depend: $(SRC_FILES)
        rm -f ./.depend
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $^ -MF  ./.depend;

include .depend

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

You might also find interest in the [`makedepend`](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0/makedepend.1.html) tool.